# How to make a channel delete reaction in discord.py(rewrite)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So, I made a command `!vx new` which creates a new channel with all the permissions of the author and admins set up, in a certain category. Now I want to create a command which deletes the ticket - `!vx close`. This was the code I figured out,it works but the problem with this is that it can receive "Yes" from any of the user in the ticket.

```
@client.command(name='close', aliases=['delete'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def close(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Do you want to delete this channel?")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user: discord.Member):

        def check(reaction, user):
            name_list = []
            for emoji in reaction.message.reactions:
                name_list.append(emoji.emoji)

            return '✅' in name_list and reaction.message.author.id == MyBotID and reaction.message.content == "Do you want to delete this channel?" and user.guild_permissions.administrator

        if check(reaction, user):
            await ctx.send("K!")
            await ctx.channel.delete()
```

I want the user who types `!vx close` to react with a cross/tick mark which will close the ticket if the author reacts with tick and will not close if the author reacts with cross.

EDIT - The above code is also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Member object from the function's Context (ctx) and the message from the `client.wait_for()`. So you can have the check function be:

```
return m.content.lower() == 'yes' and ctx.message.author == m.author
```

For the emoji bit, you can put a if statement inside the `on_reaction_add` event to say something along the lines of "if message by me (the bot) AND message content is for a close AND reaction emoji is agree AND user has permissions 'administrator' "

Emoji Code as requested:
It would look something like this.

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user : discord.Member):

        def check(reaction, user):
            name_list = []
            for emoji in reaction.message.reactions:
                name_list.append(emoji.emoji)

            return '✅' in name_list and reaction.message.author.id == yourBotsID and reaction.message.content == "Do you want to delete this channel?" and user.guild_permissions.administrator

        if check(reaction, user):
            await ctx.send("K!")
            await ctx.channel.delete()
```

Comment: I got the first part down,Thanks a lot! But I am not sure about the emoji part, can you give a sample for that as well if you don't mind, Thanks.

Comment: Sure give me a minute to figure it out.

Comment: I've just edited the solution to include the Emoji code. You'll need to change the id bit to your bots ID. This code also depends on it being in a Cog, so you should make any edits if it isn't or the variables are different.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am just trying out this code, I had a question, what is the difference between @client.command and @commands.Cog? I just do not understand what Cogs are and what do they do,

Comment: The only difference is that the event code is in a cog. A cog is just like a class containing a series of related commands. It's a way of organising your commands so that you don't have a massive bot.py file. [Docs on Cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html)

Comment: do we have to add the `@commands.Cog` after `return m.content.lower() == 'yes' and ctx.message.author == m.author` ??

Comment: and yes, i just read the docs on Cogs, I think I somewhat know their function now, Again Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey there @Kelo I have edited the question, can you please tell me what is wrong in it? because it only sends the ctx.send message of the 4th line, and nothing else, it does not even show any error on my console. I think it does not show any error cause I have put up a `@clien.event` at the start which catches errors and replies to the user with an error message. If you could help, It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't put the event inside the command. It is a stand alone bit of code. You'd put it outside any command. If your code is in the bot.py file, change the `@commands.Cog.listener()` to `client.event`

Comment: So, can I put the code you sent anywhere in my main file?
And i am so sorry for troubling you a lot, its just that I have never used a Cog before...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216378/discussion-between-kelo-and-videro).